# Is MVC simply a concept or is there more to it?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm learning about MVC and am wondering if there is more to it other than the concept of view->control->model?

What is ASP.NET's MVC, is it again just the method of splitting front end, processing and data up - as with the general idea of MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is an architectural pattern. I advice you to read the wikipedia [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) where the concept of MVC has been easy explained.

ASP.NET MVC is a framwork that implements the MVC pattern on the .NET world.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of architectural patterns. I'll have to give ASP.NET's MVC framework a go before I think I'll fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As Lorenzo said, MVC is a programming model, first described in 1979 by someone working at XEROX ([history here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC_model)). Now... what is to .NET? It allows you to have full control over your markup (clean HTML), implements latest technologies (JASON, REST), enforces newest concepts (DRY, inference, etc)... and testing.

I personally find it very powerful and interesting, in some cases easier and faster to develop websites, and I like the separation of concerns idea. Still yet have to think of standards for coding, like how to separate folders without messing up with the inference stuff, etc.

I specially love the speed (compared to webforms), since now code is cleaner (no more viewstate), mvc websites loads faster, plus now is easier to integrate with jQuery and AJAX to create better interfaces.

If you want more control over the code browser renders and you love working with the metal then .NET MVC is the choice.